# Add itemtemplate columns value as querystring in popup window genereted by Linkbutton in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Would appreciate if anyone could help me.

I have two columns in my gridview, 1st column is a templatefield for capturing rownumber of grid and 2nd column is a link button clicking on which i am opening a pop up window.

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RowNum" Visible="false"> 
<ItemTemplate> 
<asp:Label ID="lblRowNum" runat="server" Text="<%#Container.
DataItemIndex + 1>"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate> 

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FileName"> 
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Empid")%>'
CommandName="Click" OnClientClick='<%# Eval("FileName", "window.open
(\"abc.aspx\",null,\"location=0,status=0,toolbar=0,
menubar=0,resizable=1\",\"true\");")%>'/>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This works fine however i want to pass text of label(from first column) as querystring of popup window.

Could it be done in codebehind or within window.open of my javascript code which i am calling onclick event of link button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi All managed to solve it.....thanks

Comment: Can you please post your answer?